# Brownian motion and hitting time

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

I need some help with the geometrical aspect of a Brownian motion and his hitting time.
If $W$ a Brownian motion and $\tau=inf { t\ge 0  \text{  st   }  W_t > a } $  with $a \ge 0 $.
Can someone please draw the process $W_{\tau}$. Is this a stopped process meanings that after $a$ the process is stopped for ever or the process is stopped (ie: $W_s=a$ for $s<t$ such that $W_s< a$) but then  if $W_t > a $ the process is "back to normal".

Can we say that $W_t=W_{min(t,\tau)}+W_{min(t,\sigma)}$ with $\sigma= inf {  t\ge 0, W_t \ge a}$  ???

I don't know if it's clear.

Thanks

Comment: if someone has any idea please??

Comment: $W_\tau$ is not a process. It is the random variable $W_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$. What is the difference between your $\sigma$ and $\tau$?

Comment: $\sigma = inf { t \ge 0  W_t \le a } $ i did a mistake sorry

Comment: $\sigma$ is the exit time and  $\tau$ is the enter time

Answer (score 5):

I think you still misunderstand how stochastic processes, stopping times and random variables are defined, and I urge you to go back to the definitions using an underlying sample space $\Omega$ and a mapping $X : [0, T] \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

That being said, I think I understand what you are asking (in terms of what it "looks like"), because you have a decomposition in mind that might look like this:
[image]
The decomposition corresponds to
$$W_t = \color{blue}{W_{t\wedge \tau}} + \color{red}{1_{\{t \geq \tau\}}(W_t - a)},$$
where $a \wedge b = \min(a,b)$ by definition, and
$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0: W_t \geq a\}$$
and $1_A$ is the indicator function of the event $A$.

(*Note: in the picture, the red curve is shifted to "continue" the process $W_t$ after time $t$, though $G_t = \color{red}{1_{\{t \geq \tau\}}(W_t - a)}$ is continuous at $t = \tau$.*)

Yes, it is true that $W_{t\wedge \tau(\omega)}(\omega) \geq a$ for all $t \geq \tau(\omega)$, for each $\omega \in \Omega$. However, you asked:

> Can someone please draw the process $W_\tau$

No, because $W_\tau$ is *not a process*. For each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, it is a single point.

Comment: thank you very much. Everything is clear now

Comment: @MinkowskiYaacov If you consider the question answered, please accept the answer so that the thread can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $W_{0}(\omega)=0$ a.s., so $W_{\min\{t,\sigma(\omega)\}}(\omega)=W_{\sigma(\omega)}(\omega)=W_{0}(\omega)=0$, since

$$\sigma(\omega)=\inf\{t\geq 0\colon W_{t}(\omega)\leq a\},$$

for $a\geq 0$, therefore we have $\sigma(\omega)=0$ a.s..

Note that $W_{t}(\omega)\neq W_{\min\{t,\tau(\omega)\}}(\omega)$, since

$$\tau(\omega)=\inf\{t\geq 0\colon W_{t}(\omega)> a\},$$

for $a\geq 0$ and $\tau(\omega)$ is a random variable.

It may happen that $\tau(\omega)=3$, so for example $W_{10}(\omega)\neq W_{\min\{10,3\}}(\omega)$.

Comment: thanks but my question was more on the graphical interpretation of the first hitting time and exit time for a Brownian motion. How you would you drawn $W_{\sigma}$ and $W_{\tau}$ but also $W_{\sigma}+W_{\tau}$

Comment: it seems that  $W_\sigma$ is a stopped process meaning that $W=W_\sigma$ until le time $\sigma$ is reached and then $W$ is constant for ever.

Comment: I think you are messing up a stochastic process with a random variable. Your $W_{\sigma(\omega)}(\omega)$ and $W_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$ are just random variables and depend only on $\omega$. You do not have a time dependency here.

Comment: $W_\sigma=(W_{min(\sigma,t)})_{t \ge 0}$

Comment: Let's assume that for $\omega_{1}$ we have $\tau(\omega_{1})=3$. You know that $W_{\tau(\omega_{1})}(\omega_{1})=W_{3}(\omega_{1})=a$. Then for $\omega_{2}$ you can have $\tau(\omega_{2})=100$, and as a result $W_{\tau(\omega_{2})}(\omega_{2})=W_{100}(\omega_{2})=a$.

Comment: I just need someone to show me what a stopped Brownian motion look like.( with a hitting or exit time)